# Resolving own LAN IP when the network goes down

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface, raspbian, host-name-resolution

I have a headless music server (raspbian buster) running a storage server (minimserver) and a player (upmpdcli) on the same machine. When it's playing, it's fetching the music files via its LAN address. So the music is played and browsed through URLs like: `http://192.168.1.108:9790/minimserver/...`

Even though playlists are stored on the machine, when it loses WiFi connection, the stream stops immediately. I assume this is because the interface gets taken down and it can no longer access itself through the IP `192.168.1.108`.

I can't alter the system to completely access music through `localhost` because the music is enqueued and browsed by other devices on the network. So is there some way I can maintain localhost LAN address (`192.168.1.108`) resolution even when the network is down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the interface address to the `lo` (loopback) adaptor as well:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.108/32 dev lo
```

The kernel will do the right things.

Comment: This worked great! Now I just need to come to grips with interface configuration in the newer debian versions. Also I have a suspicion that maybe dhcpd could be setup to create this loopback address automatically based on the current lease. Investigations continue

Comment: If other things or users are expecting to reach it regularly, do yourself a favour and set a static address. You'll be glad you did so when you're knee-deep in packet captures trying to diagnose something apparently unrelated.